# Get agent at the head of conveyor - correct use of ConveyorPath.getAgent()?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

In my model, there is a palletizing area where a palletizer agent moves to a location adjacent to an accumulating conveyor, picks up the last box on that conveyor, and transfers it to a pallet.

I am trying to find the best way to refer to that last box on the conveyor and store it in a variable.

I am aware of `ConveyorPath.getAgent()`, documented [here](https://anylogic.help/api/com/anylogic/engine/markup/ConveyorPath.html#getAgent(int)) but it does not seem to function properly, throwing the following error:

```
Code : v_box = v_conveyorPath.getAgent(0);    
Error : Description: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Agent to Box.
```

I have gone into my conveyor markups and changed the "Material item type" fields to "Box", to no avail.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I get the ConveyorPath to return a `Box` type instead of an `Agent` type?

Thank you.

EDIT: After running tests, I can confirm that the agents present on my conveyor are of Class `Box`.

```
traceln(conveyor.getAgent(0).getClass());
Output : class modelname.Box
```

And yet I still cannot store a reference to that Box inside of a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply cast the agent you are getting as a box

`Box myBox = (Box)conveyor.getAgent(0)`

Bare in mind that this type of casting will cause an error if you have anything that is not a box on the conveyor

Read more here
https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_type_casting.asp

but if you specify in your conveyor object that the objects you have are boxes, or in this example below Cartons,

[image]

Then the get function will return an agent of that type specified, thus no casting neccesary.

[image]

The latter option is the safest and possibly more correct way of doing it in most models

Comment: Thank you Jaco-Ben for that tip about type casting. I had also thought of the second solution, but even after going through and switching every single one of the conveyors in my model to have "Box" as a Material Item Type, it still hadn't worked.

Comment: It only works on the conveyor block not the animation.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that. My model's conveyor's settings look identical to yours, and from what I can see, that is clearly the conveyor space markup shape that you have selected, not the "Convey" flowchart block.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I have no idea why yours is not working.